# Python Classes Coding

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, city, average):
    """Construct an Applicant object"""
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.city = city
    self.average = average





def getFullName(self):
    "returns the full name of the applicant in the format 'lastName, firstname'"

     return self.firstName + "," + self.lastName

def getCity(self):
    "returns the city of the Applicant"

      return self.city

def getAverage(self):
    "returns the Applicant average"

     return self.average

def getScholarshipStatus(self):
    """calculate and return the scholarship status based on the following:
    return None if average < 90
    return General if average >= 90
    """
    if self.average < 90:
        return none
    else:
        return "General"


 def getAcceptanceStatus(self):
    """calculate and return acceptance status based on criteria
    return 'accepted' if average >= 80
    return 'denied' if average < 80"""

  if average >= 80:
    return "accepted"
  else:
    return "denied"

def __str__(self):
    """returns the string interface"""

    return "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(self.firstName,self.lastName,self.city,self.average)
```

This is my Applicant python that needs to be used for my Main_Applicant module
and this is my main_applicant module

```
from applicant import *

def printAcceptanceList(applicantList):
"""Output a list applicants that were accepted"""


def printScholarshipList(applicantList):
"""Output a list applicants that qualify for scholarship"""

for applicants in applicantList:
    if applicants.getScholarshipStatus() == "General":
        print applicants





def makeApplicant(infoStr):
    """returns an Applicant object created from the infoStr"""


    appStrList = infoStr.split(",")
    firstname = appStrList[0]
    lastname = appStrList[1]
    city = appStrList[2]

    marksum = 0
    for markstr in appStrList[3:]:
        marksum = marksum + int(markstr)
    average = marksum/6

    # create the applicant object
    newApplicant = Applicant(firstname, lastname, city, average)

    return newApplicant




def getHighestApplicant(applicantList):
    """returns the Applicant with the highest average"""
    highest_average = 0
    for applicants in applicantList:
        highest_average = max()



def buildApplicantList(infoStrList):
    """returns a list of Applicants from a file list"""
    accepted_list = []
    for applicants in applicantList:
        if applicants.getAcceptanceStatus() == "Accepted":
            applicants = makeApplicant(applicants)
            accepted_list = append.applicant




def main():
    #read the text file into a list (each row in the file is an item in the list)
    file = open("applicants.csv","r")
    fileList = file.readlines()

    # assemble the collection of applicants
    applicantsList = buildApplicantList(fileList)


    printAcceptanceList(applicantsList)
    printScholarshipList(applicantsList)

    presScholarApp = getHighestApplicant(applicantsList)
    print("The Winner of the President's Scholarship is " + presScholarApp.getFullName())


main()
```

in the `main_Applicant` module, applicants.csv is something I made up with my excel as a applicants' averages, cities, and other information to use in the function
Anyone know How to make the module work?

p.s If I were to know where are the students applying from - a report on the number of students applying from each city, how should I code it?

Comment: You should probably do some debugging on it and then come back with a more focused question

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code needs to actually be wrapped in a class statement like this:

```
class Applicant:

    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, city, average):
        """Construct an Applicant object"""
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.city = city
        self.average = average





    def getFullName(self):
        "returns the full name of the applicant in the format 'lastName, firstname'"

         return self.firstName + "," + self.lastName

    def getCity(self):
        "returns the city of the Applicant"

          return self.city

    def getAverage(self):
        "returns the Applicant average"

         return self.average

    def getScholarshipStatus(self):
        """calculate and return the scholarship status based on the following:
        return None if average < 90
        return General if average >= 90
        """
        if self.average < 90:
            return none
        else:
            return "General"


     def getAcceptanceStatus(self):
        """calculate and return acceptance status based on criteria
        return 'accepted' if average >= 80
        return 'denied' if average < 80"""

      if average >= 80:
        return "accepted"
      else:
        return "denied"

    def __str__(self):
        """returns the string interface"""

        return "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(self.firstName,self.lastName,self.city,self.average)
```

otherwise the selfs and **init** method don't mean anything.

And Python has a built in CSV reader. Check out the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), it is very easy to use and very well documented

And to code what you ask you could do it multiple ways, for example you could loop through all the students and put the cities in a list then see which appears most frequently. Not sure how this would be on efficiency but it would be easy to understand and fairly straightforward to code. Good luck